# Set of measure zero - Analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Why every set of measure zero has emptiness? 
I.e, why $m(A)=0$ implies $\operatorname{int}(A)=\emptyset$, where $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

So I assumed that $m(A)=0$. By definition, $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}$ $R_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty V(R_i) < \epsilon$, where $R_i$ is a $n$-dimensional block and V is the volume of $R_i$. I assume, by absurd, $\operatorname{int}(A)\neq \emptyset$. So $\operatorname{int}(A)$ contains some open block $R_i'$, and $m(A) \geq m(R_i')>0$. So for what $m(A)=0$, the $\operatorname{int}(A)=\emptyset$. But I dont know why the last inequality is true.

Comment: Your proof looks good to me. Which last inequality?

Comment: Thanks, @simonzack. This inequality $m(R_i')>0$, I dont know how can I justify her.

Comment: Argue by induction on $ n $. For $ n=1$, use that closed intervals are compact.

Comment: In your proof, where did you use the $R_i$'s?

Comment: @ClementC. I used to ensure the existence of open block $R_i'$ contained in $int(A)$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Please, can you explain better?